# Replace specific characters in String Array

Tags: arrays, swift, string

My String Array contains multiples strings:

```
var array = ["Test", "Another Test", "Third test"]
```

I wonder how I can replace all the "e" characters in the array with "*". It´s important for me to always use my array and not create a new one.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Surely you tried *something,* didn't you? Don't hesitate to show your attempt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do something like this:

```
var array = ["Test", "Another Test", "Third test"]

for (index, str) in array.enumerated() {
    array[index] = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "*")
}
```

Or a simpler solution with `map`:

```
array = array.map({ $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "*") })
```

Both will give you:

```
["T*st", "Anoth*r T*st", "Third t*st"]
```